# Changed something in Android Build Path, now can't find some imports?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I changed my compile SDK version from API22 (5.1) to API19 (4.4). After changing it back, I can no longer build.

Android-Studio can't find some of the following:

---

**ActionBarActivity (base class for my main activity)**

**Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (parent in styles.xml)**

**Can't resolve 'R' for R.id, etc.**

---

I imagine my target SDK got messed up somewhere else in the project, but I'm not familiar enough with the Android ecosystem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - I must have switched the build API in the layout GUI, it was still on 19. One followup question - can anyone explain or point me in the right direction of the difference between android.support.v4.app.Widget, android.support.v7.app.Widget, or just android.app.Widget?

Answer (score 0):

---

it is a possibility that you have given some wrong format file name for res folder file such as images .
all file name must be in lowercase and must not contain any special characters .
try this that was worked for me for same **Can't resolve 'R' for R.id, etc.**
problem